# How to access Azure ubantu http 80 port?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-nsg

I use "flask run -p 80" to start a python web api in Azure ubantu 22.

1. I use curl to test it successfully in VM
2. I open firewall for 80
   [image]
3. I also add security rule for azure NSG, it test successfully.
   [image]

But I can not access the flask 80 portal use my local browser.
Please help to advice what i need to do next?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to access Azure ubuntu http 80 port?
> I have followed the methods below to run the application on `port 80` in the `Ubuntu VM`

> Note: For testing I deployed **NGINX**

Check if your application is listening on the correct `port 8080` for the foreign Address `0.0.0.0:*` by using below command. If not, you could find what's IP of the application consumed.

```
 #Install nettools
sudo apt install net-tools
sudo netstat -alpn | grep LISTEN
```

**Output:**

[image]

When I try with `8080`, it's not working, but it's working with 80 as below.

[image]

**NSG Rules**

Make sure to add the same port in the `NSG` as the port that is listening on the VM

[image]

When I try to access the application hosted on the Ubuntu VM using the `public IP` with `port 80`, it starts working as below.

```
20.56.41.235:80
```

[image]

If still not working disable the local firewall on `Ubuntu VM` by using the command below.

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: Yes, Venkat, you are right, The root cause is flask run command do not use the ip address 0.0.0.0