# How to connect JBoss server on port 8080 in Linux VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a 3 VM's created with Linux(Red hat) OS on port 8080. I am unable to connect to port 8080 in bastion host of the VM. Any Leads?
When I tried the command

> curl -v http://VMhostname:8080

It shows the following error message

> Trying http://VMhostname:8080...

- TCP_NODELAY set
- connect to xx.xx.xx.xx port 8080 failed: Connection refused
- Failed to connect to AzureVM1 port 8080: Connection refused
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to VMhostname port 8080: Connection refused

The service is started and is listening 127.0.0.1(localhost) on 8080 but not the IP address on VM is listening on port 8080.

netstat -ln | grep 8080 shows
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

The 2 and 3rd VM's are not listening on port 8080 either on localhost nor with IP addresses of VM's. How to set the service listen?
I checked firewall rules as well. I see none blocking the access.
I want to connect to port 8080 with the hostname of VM in all 3 VM's.
Also Can we access 1 VM on another VM? like connecting 2 servers?
I am new to Azure.
Could someone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The service is started and is listening 127.0.0.1(localhost) on 8080 but not the IP address on VM is listening on port 8080.

Check if your application is listening on the correct `port 8080` for the foreign Address `0.0.0.0:*` by using below command.

Check if any package is installed on the local VM with a service running on `port 80`. If it is not already installed, you can install a service, such as `NGINX`.

```
#Install nettools
sudo apt install net-tools
sudo netstat -alpn | grep LISTEN
```

If both `Virtual Machine's` are listening on `IP` address `0.0.0.0 with port 80`, you should be able to ping the IP address

[image]

When I try to check the communication between `VM1` and `VM2` using `port 80`, it's working as expected

[image]

When I try to access the `VM2` with port `8080` from `VM 1` it's not working but its working with only port 80.

[image]

Make sure to add the same port in the  `NSG`  as the port that is listening on the `Virtual Machine`.

[image]

Reference: [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76995115/how-to-access-azure-ubantu-http-80-port/77008286#77008286) by me about same issue.