# Can't make HTTPS work with flask on an Azure VM

Tags: azure, flask, ssl, https

A problem that seems quite simple, but it's been two hours and I can't find the solution.

I have a flask app that I run on an azure VM (with the flask development server, it is not for production).

On port 80 it works perfectly, I can access it from the public IP.

I wanted to go HTTPS, so I have generated certificates and changed my flask command to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, debug=True, ssl_context=context)` (I have the same problem with `ssl_context='adhoc'`)

[image: Log flask]

I created a new rule to allow port 443

[image: Interfaces réseau]

It works on localhost, local IP, but not on the public IP (from anywhere). Where could I have done a mistake ? (Example below with adhoc certificate)

[image: curl requests]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Can't make HTTPS work with flask on an Azure VM

If you are unable to access the Flask app with a public IP using port 443, make sure to check if the VM is listening on port 443 by using the below command.

```
sudo netstat -alpn | grep LISTEN
```

If `alpn` is not installed, kindly install it using the following command.

```
#Install nettools
sudo apt install net-tools
```

[image]

If the `VM` is not listening on port **443**, make sure to install the `HTTPS` service and enable port **443** on the firewall by following these steps.

1. Install `apache2` to enable ports **80** and **443**

```
    sudo apt-get install apache2
```

2. Open ports **80** and **443** in the firewall.

```
#List the `ufw` application profiles
      sudo ufw app list
```

> - **Apache**: It opens only port 80 (normal, unencrypted web traffic)
> - **Apache Full**: It opens both 80 (normal, unencrypted web traffic) and 443 (TLS/SSL encrypted traffic)
> - **Apache Secure** : It opens only port 443 (TLS/SSL encrypted traffic)

3. Check port status using below command

```
sudo ufw status
```

> If the firewall is not enabled, enable it using the below command

```
sudo ufw enable
```

[image]

I was unable to access the app with port 443 using the VM's public IP, even though port 443 was allowed in the NSG rules. It started working after I allowed port 443 on the VM.

**Results before enabling port 443**

[image]

**Result after enabling port 443**

[image]

The application is accessible with the public IP address

[image]

Refer [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76995115/how-to-access-azure-ubantu-http-80-port/77008286#77008286)  answered by me.