Unable to browse the Azure Ubuntu VM using its public IP in url
My Azure VM is up running, passed diagnostics. I can ssh into it, but ping public-ip failed.
Some details:
UbuntuVM:~$ curl localhost:80
Welcome to nginx!
...
But if I curled the index.html from my PC, it failed:
root@DESKTOP-7H7HR2B:/mnt/c/# curl http://52.148.136.139/index.html
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 52.148.136.139 port 80 after 21052 ms: Couldn't connect to server
I put the public IP 52.148.136.139 in the web browser url and got The connection timed out.
Both /var/log/nginx/error.log and access.log are empty.
The setup seems to be good:
$ systemctl status nginx  shows the web server is active(running)
$ vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and it has listen 80 default_server;
$ ls -al /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x 2  755 www-data 4096 Dec 19 04:12 .
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      612 Dec 19 04:12 index.html (content page)
I've also configured the networking security group inbound and outbound as below.

What could be wrong?

Can you please check the local firewall using the cmdlet sudo ufw status? If firewall is enabled, kindly allow the port 80 in firewall, Follow the Stack Overflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76995115/how-to-access-azure-ubantu-http-80-port/77008286#77008286 for more dettails.

I was logged out the ssh session and when I tried to log back and the ssh stopped working. After some diagnostics run, I went to Support+Troubleshooting and was guided to reset ssh configuration and was able to get the ssh back.


Unable to browse the Azure Ubuntu VM using its public IP in url

The error you encountered is due to firewall rules or Nginx configurations. Follow the steps below to resolve the issue.
Verify the VM's firewall status using the cmdlet: sudo ufw status. If the firewall is disabled, there is no need to open port 80. If it is enabled, ensure that HTTP traffic is allowed.

sudo ufw allow 80/tcp

Check that Nginx is running and correctly configured to listen on port 80 by navigating to /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file.
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Make sure that theserver block contains the correct rootand⁣index directives.
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

You can run the following command to verify that the index.html file exists in the directory.
ls -l /var/www/html/index.html

Test Nginx Configuration
sudo nginx -t

Reload Nginx to apply the changes.
sudo systemctl reload nginx


Ensure that Nginx has the correct permissions to access the index.html file
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/index.html
sudo chmod 644 /var/www/html/index.html

NSG Rule:

If all the configurations are correct, try to access the site, and it should display the index.html content.
http://172.191.87.244/index.html



@venkat I followed your steps with ufw disable as well as allow 80/tcp and it still failed. I tried telnet 52.148.136.139 80 and 8080, both failed. I then noticed the NSG rule Name has a yellow triangle. Once I added a rule with the Src Port ranges changed to Any *, there are no more yellow signs and the index.html is successfully displayed.

telnet 52.148.136.139 80 also works.

It makes sense because the src port is assigned by the OS (operating system) randomly. Each process (browser instance) is tied to a unique TCP socket. The OS will assign a new source port for every new connection initiated by each process so that the OS can differentiate these connections by different source ports for each instance of the browser. Two instances of a web browser accessing the same URL (same destination IP and port 80) will typically have different source ports.
